# Selector definition with Testcafe

Tags: automation, css-selectors, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

I build up some tests with a selector

```
.click(Selector('div').withText('19233456').nth(9).find('.np-folder-fave'))
```

Works well. But in some situations it is possible that there is also a test folder 192334567. So I tried to get a more saved method to select the item, but it is not possible. I tried:

```
.click(Selector('div').withExactText('19233456').nth(9).find('.np-folder-fave'))
```

But this will fail. I tried a very saved way:

```
.click(Selector('div').withAttribute('title', '19233456').find('.np-folder-fave'))
```

Do not work. Only in the first case the item is selected/clicked.
The element in the page is:

```
<div class="np-folder" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<div class="np-folder-name" title="19233456">19233456</div>
<div class="np-folder-fave"></div>
</div>
```

The div fave will cause a popup menu.
Why it is not possible to click a selector with the exact text in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The [`find`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#find) method searches among descendants of elements in the matching set. The `np-folder-fave` div is not a descendant but a sibling of the `np-folder-name` div. So the same Selector with the [`sibling`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#sibling) method should work:

```js
Selector('div').withAttribute('title', '19233456').sibling('.np-folder-fave')
```